# AJAX Tabbed Panel not visible on running the website

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have been trying all day but the ajax tabbed panel wont show when i press F5. No matter what. (Note i have copied and pasted the source code for tabbed pannel from internet.)
the top of the page has:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

the tabbed panel etc appeared as this :

it did not work so i changed it to:

```
<asp:TabPanel ID="tbpnluser" runat="server" >
```

Comment: try to put a HeaderText in your TabPanel, and inside that panel, put a contentemplate.

Comment: I have those elements, i just gave out one line to tell that i have replaced ajax: with asp: everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this..

[Ajax Tabs](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Tabs/Tabs.aspx)

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer Id="Tabs" runat="server" 
        Height="150px"
        Width="400px"
        ActiveTabIndex="1"
        >
    <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" Id="tbpnluser"
         HeaderText="Sample"
        Enabled="true"
        <ContentTemplate>
            You will place here what you want to display.
        </ContentTemplate>
    />
</ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```